# Is there a way to use the class or id of a text link for an if statement in php?

Tags: php

my purpose is to send a "variable" through a text link, but not in the url, so I will make a check using PHP.

So, the page will check if the referred had a class=something or id=something.

Thank you.

Comment: Is this a form or something? If not, why not AJAX?

Comment: what do you mean by 'text link'?

Comment: Clear as mud. Give an example of what you want to do. I suspect the answer is "no, cannae do it."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's impossible. You should pass it through GET/POST parameters or add it to request headers.

Comment: Not really. OP **can** parse the whole HTML for a variable from the referer url but this is very very unreliable.

Comment: Or he can put text "call me and tell where are you from" on the page, right :)

Comment: @Punkis The answer is "use headers if you REALLY can't use parameters"

Comment: Depends on how you would like to send your request

Comment: What is a 'text link' at last?!